# How to associate “owner” with default User model?

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-rest-framework

I’m trying to teach myself Django and the Django Rest Framework, but I'm having a hard time understanding how object ownership is defined.

I want to apply the custom “IsOwnerOrReadOnly” permissions given in the DRF documentation with the default User model.  My goal: Users will be able to PUT/PATCH/DELETE the information in their own account, but won't be able to change any other users’ information.

My user serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    rides = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True, queryset = Ride.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
         fields = [
            'pk',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'rides'
        ]
        write_only_fields = ['password']
        read_only_fields = ['pk', 'username']
```

The `IsOwnerOrReadOnly` code:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

The problem is with the line `return obj.owner == request.user`.  It always returns `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'owner’`.  Why is the "owner" of a user not the user itself?  How can I say “owner = this object” so that my permissions classes work?

Follow-up question: I would like to eventually extend the default User model to add more fields.  Would my permissions still work if I made a new User model by inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`?  (I just started learning Django, so I'm not entirely sure what the process for creating a new User model would be.  But I thought it might be good to mention in case that would change how I define permissions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because there's no such abstract concept as owner for all models. You will have to define the relationship between the object and the user in the model and apply that in the permission for each model.

In this case, you want to be sure that the user is trying to modify his own user object so you can just do this:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj == request.user
```

So in essence, this will only work for the User model and you will have to extend it to work for other models based on the relationship of the model with the user.

You may want to define different permission classes for each resource than trying to put all the logic in the same permission class.

As for your question on extending the user model. This [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) in the docs explains the different methods of extending the existing user model which is basically by either extending from the `AbstractUser` or `AbstractbaseUser`. The Django permissions framework will still work as it is implemenmted against those base classes.

Bear in mind however that DRF permission classes are different from Django permissions. You can Django permissions to implement the logic inside the permission classes but they can be implemented without the permissions.

**EDIT FROM COMMENT**

If you have a `Ride` model with owner, you can do this to combine them.

```
 class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True
            if isinstance(obj, Ride):
                return obj.owner == request.user
            return obj == request.user
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  In your option, what would be the best way to extend `IsOwnerOrReadOnl`y to work for other models?  I was trying to use the IsOwnerOrReadOnly permissions for both the User model and a Ride model.  Each user is the "owner" of one or more rides.  If I have `obj.owner == request.user`, it will work for Ride objects, but if I have `obj == request.user`, it will work for User objects.  Should I just write two separate permissions classes for each model, even though they'd be identical but for the last line?  Or is there a more DRY way to do this?

Comment: It will generally be better to have different permission classes as you may need to add another logic later but if you want to combine them, you can first check the type of the object, then check for the appropriate permission

Comment: @Ansley Do check out `drfaddons` at https://github.com/101loop/drf-addons Gonna write a detailed answer to explain how I do this.

Answer (score 0):

### Ownership

Say there is a `Model A`. To define ownership, you need to create a field in `Model A` that will point to `User` model. You can do this easily. Make sure you use `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` for same.

### Getting a list of owned objects from API

When it comes to getting a list of objects owned by the authenticated user (`request.user`), you are looking at creating a filter. To do same there are two ways:

- Create a filter class and use in it `generic views`. This is more extensible. I have done same in `drfaddons.filters.IsOwnerFilterBackend`. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/101Loop/drf-addons/blob/master/drfaddons/filters.py).
- Override `def filter_queryset(self, queryset)` in each API Class.

### Ensuring in Retrieve/Update/Delete

This time you want to make sure that permission check is being applied. Here, you will want to implement `has_object_permission` and `has_permission` from `permissions.BasePermission` which you're doing.

In general, you'll want to use both `filtering` and `permission` check.

## Implementing across the project

To implement this across the whole project, you need to set your `filter` and `permission` as default one in `settings.py`'s `REST_FRAMEWORK` configuration. You'll also need to ensure that an owner field (with same name preferably) is present in each model. (Check `Abstract` model).

I have done same in all my project and hence, I have created a package of the same. Check [DRF Addons](https://github.com/101loop/drf-addons). You can also install it via pip: `pip install drfaddons`. It will do all of the above said task.